# Array containing objects has wrong length

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, loops

I have an array like:

`errors = [ {...}, {...}, {...} ]`

It's an `instanceof` array, yet it only returns 1 for `.length`?

Relevant code:

```
if(data.error){
  errors.push({'element':ele,error:data.error});
}

//Above is looped a few times and there are N number of errors now inside

console.log(errors) //Returns 2+ objects like {...}, {...}
console.log(errors.length) //Returns 1
```

For Uzi and Muirbot, here's the errors array:

```
[
Object
element: b.fn.b.init[1]
error: "You must enter "example" into the field to pass"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
element: b.fn.b.init[1]
error: "Crap!"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Can you please add code example that reproduces this case?

Comment: can you paste exactly the output of console.log(errors)

Comment: Thanks for posting an example but it's usually much more helpful to post a test case on http://jsfiddle.net/ so that it is reproducible. The dump as you posted it should not be causing this behaviour.

Comment: hmm, if no one knows why i can post all the code, but it's quite large as it's part of an internal library. I felt as tho the code above should be enough since it literally all takes place there basically. But yes, ill post a test case in like 10 mins

Comment: @Oscar Godson: If not possible, then could you perhaps make a screenshot of a console in which you can show the result of both logs? Copying text may eliminate important details.

Comment: Hold on. Working on a test case. Trying to remove the AJAXy stuff

Comment: Please provide it as http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: What if you log `errors.slice()` instead? That way you make a copy which will stay unchanged (in case of some async stuff which is adding elements later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Chrome's Web Inspector's console.log is an async event. So, the length was a property lookup so it gave that back instantly, but the object with two items inside was held off until the rest of the events had fired.

In the future I, and others with this issue, should use `debugger;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, this code:

```
var errors = new Array();

errors.push({'element':'ele', error:'data.error'});
```

...adds ONE object to the array.  The object has two properties.

Comment: Huh? The .push() is run 1,2,1000 times. No matter how many times i push new elements in .lenth === 1

Comment: That is not what your question states.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your code is executing in an order other than what you're expecting. ie, when you log both `errors` and `errors.length`, `errors` does contain only 1 object. But after that you are adding to the `errors` array, and only after that are you looking at the console. At that point you could see a larger array in `errors` for two reasons - first, your actual code isn't logging `errors` but some object that contains `errors`. In that case the console display is live, and will show you not what was in `errors` at the time, but what is in it now. Alternatively, the console could just be taking some time to log `errors`.

Without more code I can't be sure if this is the case. But you could verify it by replacing `console.log(errors);` with `console.log(errors[1]);`. If errors is really only 1 long at the time, it will log `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, [1] will return undefined since the length is only 1. The strange thing is tho that it logs errors correctly if i log it each time errors are pushed inside.

Comment: If you're saying you just tested it and got that result, then you've got your answer. Both calls to `console.log` (in your example) are executed when `errors` really is only 1 long, and you're pushing errors later (which is why logging right after you push them returns the correct result).

Answer (score -1):

> is it an Array object or something that resembles it?
>
> arrays do work:
>
> ```
> > a = [{a:1}, {b:2}]
> [Object, Object]
> > a.length
> 2
> ```
>
> you'll have to provide more code.

and now that you've provided the relevant code, the correct answer is [what Steve Wellens said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8719823/226201) (which was downvoted, by the way).

Array.push adds a single element, objects may have more than one key but they're still a single object so your real case was different from your original example, which of course works.

---

another possibility:

```
> a = []
[]
> a.length = 2
2
> a
[]
> a.length
2
> a instanceof Array
true
```

Comment: But the question says that `.push()` is called mulitple times: "Above is looped a few times and there are N number of errors now inside".

Comment: then it's a fake array, which was my first guess; objects in javascript are dynamic so you can create an array and override the length but at this point I'm guessing there's something wrong with the question itself.